# Async iterator complains about unexpected token "*"

Tags: typescript, async-await, generator

I have a TS class which has the following asynchronous generator defined as a public accessor:

```
/**
 * Provides a way to iterate through the templates, one
 * channel at a time.
 */
public async *iterator() {
  let output: IDictionary = {};
  const substitutions = this.isListDataset
    ? this._substitutions
    : [this._substitutions];
  yield this._channels.map(async function*(channel) {
    const fn = await this.compileTemplate(this._topic, channel);
    const output: ITemplateChannel = {
      channel,
      templates: []
    };
    this._substitutions.map((data: IDictionary) => {
      output.templates.push(fn(data));
    });

    yield output;
  });
}
```

The editor (**vs-code**) is happy enough with this declaration but if I run `ts-node` over the class definition it complains:

> Unexpected token *

Ok I do know that library support asyncIterators and generators needs to configured for but my `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["esnext.asynciterable", "esnext", "es2015.generator"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*-spec.ts"]
}
```

What am I missing?

---

Note: I am noticing that if I change the `yield output` to `yield* output` as I guess it *should* be ... **vs-code** points out that:

[image]

Ok now I read about that dependency but I'm unclear on how I would go about implementing it. My failed attempt was to add this method to the class:

```
public [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
  return Symbol.asyncIterator || Symbol.for("Symbol.asyncIterator");
}
```

but guessing somehow I need to map it into the `map` function? Is that right? Or maybe the `iterator` method itself? Possibly both? Confused.

Comment: Using `yield` will return the value of `output`. Using `yield*` will return the next value from `output` as an iterable/another generator.

Comment: so do you agree with me that using `yield*` is what should be used here?